# Linking with native code requires Indie (or higher) license

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have been developing apps in Xamarin.iOS for quite a while. I have an indie version of the license. Today I updated Xamarin Studio to the latest version.
When I try to debug the app it gives me the following errors:

```
/Users/crs/Projects/MyIkubiOS/MyIkubiOS/MyIkubiOS.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets (_CompileToNative target) ->

    MTOUCH: error MT9002: Linking with native code requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9002: Linking with native code requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.Int32 FFImageLoading.PlatformPerformance::task_info(System.IntPtr,System.Int32,FFImageLoading.PlatformPerformance/mach_task_basic_info&,System.Int32&)` from `System.Nullable`1<FFImageLoading.PlatformPerformance/mach_task_basic_info> FFImageLoading.PlatformPerformance::GetResidentSize()` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.IntPtr ApiDefinition.Messaging::IntPtr_objc_msgSend(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)` from `System.Void WebP.Touch.WebPDecoder::.ctor()` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.IntPtr ApiDefinition.Messaging::IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)` from `System.Void WebP.Touch.WebPDecoder::.ctor()` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.IntPtr ApiDefinition.Messaging::IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)` from `UIKit.UIImage WebP.Touch.WebPDecoder::ImageWithWebP(System.String)` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.IntPtr ApiDefinition.Messaging::IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)` from `UIKit.UIImage WebP.Touch.WebPDecoder::ImageWithWebP(System.String)` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007: P/invoking `System.IntPtr ApiDefinition.Messaging::IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)` from `UIKit.UIImage WebP.Touch.WebPDecoder::ImageWithWebPData(Foundation.NSData)` (user code) requires Indie (or higher) license.
    MTOUCH: error MT9007
```

The official pricing page in Xamarin.iOS has information about Xamarin Studio and Visual Enterprise but does not has information about Indie or Business Licenses

Answer (score 0):

Update Xamarin.iOS as well as Xamarin Studio. These errors are gone in the latest version.